# Cronjobs in Docker container how get them running?

Tags: docker, debian, cron

I've got some cronjobs in my debian docker container. They don't start automatically why?

Do I have to do some workarounds?

Comment: Are you running cron in your container?

Comment: yes I did this: /etc/init.d/cron start

Comment: Don't have a docker file. I've connected via ssh to the server and run `/etc/init.d/cron start`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running containers in docker, you can add cron tasks on the docker host machine to execute commands in the docker containers.

For example, to run 'stress' application in your container every 5 minutes you can add the following (substituting your container ID of course) to your crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * docker exec c78ddbed4ad9 /bin/sh -c 'stress -d 1 --hdd-bytes 64M --cpu 1 --io 2 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 64M --timeout 60s' >> /tmp/cronstress.log 2>&1
```

I am running this as root user on the docker host.

or just run cron:

```
root@dockerhost:cron
```

Comment: Okay but those cronjobs were genereted from an rails application, isn't there a way to run them in container?

Comment: or just run cron:    *root@dockerhost:cron*

Comment: From host? How do i set up?

Comment: The user in the cron statement is missing. The code should be: 
*/5 * * * * username docker exec c78ddbed4ad9 /bin/sh ... etc.

Answer (score 3):

Run cron daemon in docker container first. When login to container, in shell run follow command:

```
cron
```

Then jobs will start regularly.

Comment: I got this error: cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 14782: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: It mean cron is already running. So my solution will not help you. Are you sure that jobs did not start? Can you try smth simple like `*/1 * * * * echo "testmessage" >> /tmp/crontestfile` ?

Comment: yeah I'm sure I should get mails and in my logfiles there should stay somethings

Answer (score 2):

Where did you start cron? In a *Dockerfile*? There doing it within a `RUN` won't work because that process will not keep running. You need to do that e.g. via `CMD`. A better idea would be using a [suzpervisord](http://supervisord.org/).

Comment: Don't have a docker file. I've connected via ssh to the server and run /etc/init.d/cron start

Answer (score 0):

cronjob is not starting the logrotation in docker container.
my cronjob looks as below:

30 9    * * *   root    /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/apache2

Also I have added below script as ENTRYPOINT in docker file to start cron.

## !/bin/bash

/etc/init.d/cron start

Comment: is this an answer or are you sharing an observation?