# Scheduling cron inside docker container

Tags: docker, cron, logstash, containers, logrotate

I was trying to schedule a `cron` job inside `docker` based `logstash` application.

The `cron` job is as follows:

```
   30 10 * * * root logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/logstash
```

The cron is not getting executed inside container but when I execute the above command manually it works fine.

```
 # logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/logstash
 # ls -l /usr/share/logstash/logs/
 total 36
 -rw-r--r-- 1 logstash logstash    17 Jan  2 10:16 logstash.log
 -rw-r--r-- 1 logstash logstash 10701 Jan  2 10:16 logstash.log.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a duplicate of [Cronjobs in Docker container how get them running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654125/cronjobs-in-docker-container-how-get-them-running)

It basically says, that you need to make sure, that 
`/etc/init.d/cron start`
 is running.

Comment: /etc/init.d/cron start does not work inside container. Executed using crond command and then the cron job is working fine